# Envoy gateway Not assigned address

Tags: envoyproxy

Hello I am trying to deploy envoy-gateway in K8s. I had created a deployment as mentioned in the envoy sample Github repo.
The deployment is successful but somehow envoy didn't assign a IP address for me.
Pasting the snippet of kubectl describe output for envoy-gateway.

```
Spec:
  Gateway Class Name:  example-gateway-class
  Listeners:
    Allowed Routes:
      Namespaces:
        From:  Same
    Name:      http
    Port:      80
    Protocol:  HTTP
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-05-24T16:46:53Z
    Message:               The Gateway has been scheduled by Envoy Gateway
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                Accepted
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Accepted
    Last Transition Time:  2023-05-24T16:46:53Z
    Message:               No addresses have been assigned to the Gateway
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                AddressNotAssigned
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Programmed
  Listeners:
    Attached Routes:  3
    Conditions:
      Last Transition Time:  2023-05-24T16:46:54Z
      Message:               Listener is ready
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Programmed
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Programmed
    Name:                    http
    Supported Kinds:
      Group:  gateway.networking.k8s.io
      Kind:   HTTPRoute
      Group:  gateway.networking.k8s.io
      Kind:   GRPCRoute
Events:       <none>
```

Also attaching the entire Deployment file

```
# This file contains the base resources that the docs/user/HTTP_ROUTING.md guide relies on.
# This includes a GatewayClass, Gateway, Services and Deployments that are used as backends
# for routing traffic.
kind: GatewayClass
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: example-gateway-class
  labels:
    example: http-routing
spec:
  controllerName: gateway.envoyproxy.io/gatewayclass-controller
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: example-gateway
  labels:
    example: http-routing
spec:
  gatewayClassName: example-gateway-class
  listeners:
    - name: http
      protocol: HTTP
      port: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-svc
  labels:
    example: http-routing
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: example-backend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-backend
  labels:
    app: example-backend
    example: http-routing
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-backend
          image: gcr.io/k8s-staging-ingressconformance/echoserver:v20221109-7ee2f3e
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: example-route
  labels:
    example: http-routing
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: example-gateway
  rules:
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: PathPrefix
            value : /
    - backendRefs:
        - name: example-svc
          port: 8080
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!!